# CRAN package check finds warning that R CMD check --as-cran doesn't

Tags: r, cran

I recently submitted a package to CRAN and received the following errors.

WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME

checking for code which exercises the package ... WARNING
No examples, no tests, no vignettes

I ran R CMD check  --as-cran using R 3.0.2 on OSX and the only note reported was 'New submission'. No warnings were reported.

Is there an alternate way to run all of the tests that CRAN will run on a package before submitting it?

Comment: Not that I know of -- I have found other discrepancies between the local `R CMD check` and what CRAN does with a submittal.   However, those warnings clearly point out that your package is missing certain common items ('examples' etc) which are not strictly required of a package.

Comment: Try testing it on the development version. http://cran.r-project.org/sources.html The only problem with this is that you will have to compile it yourself, which requires a fortran compiler. Beyond that, some information as to the structure of your package would be helpful (i.e. do you have any folders entitled "vignettes" with nothing in it?)

Comment: one option is to try building it on http://win-builder.r-project.org/ under both the release and development branches ...

Comment: You could try a docker container like I described here: stackoverflow.com/a/33202985/2161065

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to test the package in different os.

```
devtools::check_rhub() # All os
devtools::check_win_devel() # windows
devtools::check_win_release() # windows
devtools::check_win_oldrelease() # windows
```

Or with continuous integration:

```
usethis::use_github_actions() # all os
usethis::use_travis() # osx and linux
usethis::use_appveyor() # windows
usethis::use_circleci()
```

There are way more, but these are the most famous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By using win builder

http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx

You just have to upload your source files and you will get the results in email within 5-10 minutes.

Note: Don't forget to mention your email in maintainer field